# Change password by connecting to mysql database

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

There's an error in the line " adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE user SET Password WHERE Password ='" & txtpassword.Text & "'") "

How can i fix that?

```
Private Sub getdbdata()

    Try
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;username=root;database=bank")

        dataset = New DataSet
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE user SET Password WHERE Password ='" & txtpassword.Text & "'")
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "user")

        mysqlconn.Open()

        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Visible = False

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Password change unsuccessful.")
        End If


        reader.Close()
        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: And what does the error say? Aside from being vulnerable to SQL injection, I don't see anything wrong with it. Maybe your password contains a single quote? :)

Comment: If I had to guess, which I do because you haven't bothered to provide the error message that the system provided to you, then I'd say that "user" is a reserved word and needs to be escaped if being used an identifier.  You do that in MySQL by wrapping the values in graves (`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is with the syntax of [update Query.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

so make this change in your code:

```
    dataset = New DataSet
    adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE user SET Password = '" & txtNewpassword.Text & "' " & _
                                   "WHERE userName = '" & txtuser.Text & "' and " & _
                                   "Password ='" & txtOldpassword.Text & "'")
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "user")
```

Now the code is meaning full, it will reset the password as what in txtNewpassword for the user having username in `txtuser` and matching password in `txtOldpassword`

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Settings
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host =localhost;user id=root;password=;database=cidb")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from usertbl where uname='" & user.Text & "'and upassword= '" & Pword.Text & "'"

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Settings()
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Username or Password!")
        End If

    End Sub

 Private Sub Settings()
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host =localhost;user id=root;password=;database=cidb")
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "update usertbl set upassword='" & NewPword.Text & "' where uname= '" & usertxt.Text & "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("You're successfully change your Password!")
            usertxt.Text = " "
            Pwordtxt.Text = " "
            Newuser.Text = " "
           con.Close()
    End Sub
```